# Motors that would work in a vacuum

Tags: mechanical-engineering

What are some examples of motors, preferably less than $300, that would be able to function in a vacuum?

Comment: related to this : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/28683/10902 ?

Comment: Any electric motor works in vacuum.

Comment: One caution; a suitable grease must be used.

Comment: @peterh True, but cooling is a consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to afford a real vacuum rated motor on a budget. BUT, as others have said almost any motor will work in a vacuum, so you will need to "rate" it yourself. Consider the factors that may cause the motor to fail, for example lack of cooling, tin whisker growth, insulation failure, lubricant issues etc. Then ultimately you will need to run some tests. This is what you would be paying for if you bought a motor that was rated for vacuum from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider that your motor does not nesseserily need to be in the vacuum (unless you are in space). There exist several of the shelf components that allow you to connect a shaft through the wall your vacuum container without leakage. This will make your design much simpler.

Second many electric motors will work in vaccum, but they will have hard time getting rid of heat since many systems are air cooled. However there are structural methods you can use to conduct the heat away from the system. This also applies to all your other components.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by shelf component?

Comment: "of the shelf" is a english idom meaning regular stuff that you can buy oit of a store and not wait untill it gets built for you. Store bought.